# .htaccess 301 redirect for images from old image to new image

Tags: html, image, .htaccess, redirect

I am currently using images on my site with non descriptive file names such as `kejr09238u30sdkfh.jpg`. I will be renaming these images to something like `descriptive-file-name.jpg` for SEO reasons.
currently 6 images renamed.

how to write 301 redirection?

**example**

`mysite.com/images/123.jpg`  **Renamed to** `mysite.com/images/abc.jpg`

Can you guys help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use simple `redirect` command:

```
# Redirect old file path to new file path
Redirect 301 /images/123.jpg http://example.com/images/abc.jpg
```